# Were the אוּרִ֥ים Urim & תֻמִּֽים Thummim ever returned (after the Babylonian exile) to fulfill Ezra 2:63?

Tags: ezra, second-temple-judaism, urim-and-tummim

In Ezra 2:63, invalid kohanim could not eat at the second temple until אוּרִ֥ים Urim & תֻמִּֽים Thummim approved their meals with valid levites :

> "The Tirshatha ordered them not to eat of the most holy things until a priest with Urim and Thummim should appear." ( וַיֹּ֤אמֶר הַתִּרְשָׁ֙תָא֙ לָהֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֥ר לֹא־יֹאכְל֖וּ מִקֹּ֣דֶשׁ הַקֳּדָשִׁ֑ים עַ֛ד עֲמֹ֥ד כֹּהֵ֖ן לְאוּרִ֥ים וּלְתֻמִּֽים )

- **Did the אוּרִ֥ים Urim & תֻמִּֽים Thummim get returned to Jerusalem (after the Babylonian exile) to allow [Ezra 2:63] to be fulfilled?**

Answer (score 2):

Ezra 2:63 (and its parallel in Neh 7:65) says:

> The governor ordered them not to eat the most holy things until there
> was a priest to consult the Urim and Thummim.

This can be understood in two ways:

1. It refers to a priest with the Urim and Thummim
2. It refers to a priest of sufficient rank (a descendant of the High Priest) was among the priests.  This means that it refers to the priest alone and does not necessarily include the Urim and Thummim.

We have no records of whether the Urim and Thummim -

- existed or not after the Babylonian captivity
- If they did exist, whether they we consulted or not

There is no record of the Urim and Thummim ever being consulted after the time of David (1 Sam 28:6, 30:7).

**APPENDIX** - Extract from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urim_and_Thummim

Although Josephus argues that the Urim and Thummim continued to function until the era of the Maccabees,[25] Talmudic sources are unanimous in agreeing that the Urim and Thummim stopped functioning much earlier, when Jerusalem was sacked by the Babylonians.[26][27][28] In a passage from the part of the Book of Ezra which overlaps with the Book of Nehemiah, it is mentioned that individuals who were unable to prove, after the Babylonian captivity had ended, that they were descended from the priesthood before the captivity began, were required to wait until priests in possession of Urim and Thummim were discovered;[29] this would appear to confirm the statements in the Talmud that the Urim and Thummim had by then been lost.[1][4][3] Indeed, since the priestly source, which textual scholars date to a couple of centuries prior to the captivity, does not appear to know what the Urim and Thummim looked like, and there is no mention of the Urim and Thummim in the deuteronomic history beyond the death of David, scholars suspect that use of them decayed some time before the Babylonian conquest,[3] probably as a result of the growing influence of prophets at that time.[4]

Maimonides[30] states that in the Second Temple the Urim and Thummim actually existed but no longer functioned in the practical sense since the priests no longer possessed the Holy Spirit. Rabbi Abraham ben David disagrees and maintains that during that era, the Urim and Thummim were completely absent.[9]

Answer (score 2):

By Pharisaical tradition[1], none of the holy articles from Solomon's Temple were recovered, which was why the Essenes considered the second temple illegitimate. There was no rod of Aaron, no Ark, etc. Also according to Nehemiah 7.64-65, the Urimm and Thummim were not available when the second temple was being built.

> These sought their registration among those enrolled in the
> genealogies, but it was not found there, so they were excluded from
> the priesthood as unclean. The governor told them that they were not
> to partake of the most holy food until a priest with Urim and Thummim
> should arise.

But the Urimm & Thummim were just some type of divining tool[2], most likely (although this is speculation) dice with letters inscribed on them which were carried in the High Priest's breastplace and he could retrieve them and cast them for answers to questions. Thus one could manufacture another set of dice just as they made another set of priestly garments, a new table of shewbread, a new menora, new curtains, new bronze vessels, new brazen altar, etc. E.g. the idea wasn't that the dice were made of magic material, but that God worked through them because they were carried in the High Priest's breastplate, just as the brazen altar was not accepted because it was made of magical bronze, but because it was dedicated in the temple.

But even if they did make another set, by tradition the U&T "ceased"[3] when "the former prophets" died out  -- e.g. if they were dice with letters on the sides, then rolling them would make gibberish if they were not divinely controlled.

[1] Remember, though, that Pharisees were not allowed in the Holy place nor in the Holy of Holies. The Sadduccees administered the Second Temple and they were enemies of the Pharisees, rejecting the notion that the Pharisees had access to an oral tradition that skipped over the Priestly class, but we do not have access to the traditions of the Priestly class, we only have access to the traditions of the Pharisees (the rabbinical class), where there is the following revelation, inferred from a missing "h" in the spelling of a word in Haggai:

> E. But was it present in the second sanctuary?
>
> Didn’t R. Samuel bar Inia say, “What is the meaning of the verse of
> Scripture, ‘And I will take pleasure in it and I will be glorified’
> (Haggai 1:8)? Why is the word for ‘take pleasure in it’ written
> without the expected H? It is to indicate that in five aspects, the
> first sanctuary differed from the second: the ark, the ark cover, the
> Cherubim, the fire, the Presence of God, the Holy Spirit [prophecy],
> and the Oracle Plate”?
>
> F. Say: they were present, but they did not do so much good as they had.
> *Neusner, J. (2011). The Babylonian Talmud: A Translation and Commentary (Vol. 5a, p. 67). Peabody, MA: Hendrickson Publishers.*

[2] See https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/the-urim-and-thummim for an overview with links to the relevent Talmudic texts for more info.

[3]
With the same caveats (e.g. the Pharisees were not the Priestly classes, nor were they allowed to call for the U&T), we have according to the Mishna:

> When the former prophets died out, the Urim and Tummim were cancelled.
> *Neusner, J. (1988). The Mishnah : A new translation (p. 464). New Haven, CT: Yale University Press.*

Answer (score 0):

Exodus 28:30

> Also put the **Urim** and the **Thummim** in the breastpiece, so they may be over Aaron’s heart whenever he enters the presence of the LORD. Thus Aaron will always bear the **means of making decisions for the Israelites** over his heart before the LORD.

Urim and Thummim were physical objects that had limited intrinsic/physical value. Its value was derived from God when God was using them via the high priest. When God was not using them, they were worthless to the Babylonians. I don't think it was that important whether the Babylonians had ever taken them or returned them.
Because in any case, they didn't carry the same significance as they did before the exile.  As pointed out by Dottard, "There is no record of the Urim and Thummim ever being consulted after the time of David (1 Sam 28:6, 30:7)."

However, the practice of casting lots continued.
Proverbs 16:33

> The lot is cast into the lap, but its every decision is from the LORD.

The last mention of this practice is in
Acts 1:26

> Then they cast lots, and the lot fell to Matthias; so he was added to the eleven apostles.

After that, the Holy Spirit took over. John 14:26

> But the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I have said to you.